# NPM / Nodejs: Can't install scrypt@6.0.3

Tags: node.js, installation, npm-install, node-gyp, scrypt

Actually I am trying to install `express-basic-auth`, but it fails due to the installation of `scrypt@6.0.3`. I already tried:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and also tried deleting `~/.node-gyp` as stated here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809, but none of the suggestions helped. I still get the same error:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/user/code/a/b/node_modules/scrypt/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.20.0-042000-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/code/a/b/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v9.11.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN b@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2018-12-30T20_52_24_060Z-debug.log
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: which command you used to install `express-basic-auth`?

Comment: sudo npm install express-basic-auth

Comment: If you installing this for particular project, then use it without `sudo` or if you want it globally then install it with `-g`, i.e. `npm install -g express-basic-auth`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by installing an earlier version of node locally, in my case the node 8.10.0 version. I stopped getting the same error you are getting here. Delete your node modules and package-lock.json then run

```
npm install --save node@earlierversion
npm install rest of packages
```

That's what I did to rebuild my node modules and prevent this error.

Comment: This worked for me.
Had various command line build tools installed after the node-gyp catalina.md readme, but nothing helped.


scrypt@6.0.3 build failed with latest node-gyp and latest node@v12 LTS


I could make it work using node version 8.10.0 strangely without changing anything else.